# Detect last visible nscollectionview item prototype

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

How is it possible to detect in NSCollectionView when the last item is visible on scrolling ?

I was looking for a similar solution as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235552/how-to-know-we-reached-the-last-row-of-nstableview) but [NSCollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCollectionView_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCollectionView/itemAtIndex:) doesnt have a similar layout methods.

Any hints ?

Comment: Can't you use the scroll view to do that?

Comment: @Volker How can I do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169355/callbacks-when-an-nsscrollview-is-scrolled gives pointers.

Comment: @Volker I am already using that for NSTableView but NSScrollView has only one notification `boundsDidChange` which alone is not enough to check if it has reached the end. Atleast I am not able to figure it out ...

Comment: But you can check the bounds and determine whee the document view got scrolled to?!

Comment: @Volker I was looking for some delegates as in iOS. Not quite used to Mac app programming yet :D That should do thanks !

Comment: I have posted it as answer so others can more easily see what to do in such a situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get noted when the scroll view has scrolled by registering for `boundsDidChange` notification of the document view as described here [Callbacks When an NSScrollView is Scrolled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169355/callbacks-when-an-nsscrollview-is-scrolled) .

That way one can check which part of the content of the collection view is displayed.